# How to dynamically look up shell variable name

Tags: bash, shell, control-characters

I have this situation:

```
zmx_stderr='\033[1;35m'
zmx_stdout='\033[1;36m'


tag='foobar'

tailing(){
  echo "tailing logs for ${tag} ...";
  while read line; do
   echo -e "$zmx_${1} $tag $1${zmx_no_color}: $line"
  done;
}
```

someone calls tailing() with:

```
tailing stderr
tailing stdout
```

how can I look up the zmx_stdout and zmx_stderr dynamically?

This doesn't work:

```
$zmx_${1}
```

I just get this:

```
stdout foobar stdout:
```

but I am looking for:

```
foobar stdout:
```

with control chars being generated.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a helper variable to build the name of the target variable and then use variable indirection:

```
zmx_var=zmx_$1
echo -e "${!zmx_var} $tag $1${zmx_no_color}: $line"
```

Answer (score 1):

With bash version 4.4 (I think) and above, you can use a "nameref"

```
$ foo_bar=hello
$ set -- bar
$ declare -n "var=foo_$1"
$ echo "$var"
hello
```